# Integrate okta with Django admin login form

Tags: python, django, openid-connect, okta

I am trying to add okta OIDC integration in one of my Django sites. The site has 2 apps and these apps are using admin views only and we are not using any custom view. I want to allow users to log in from the default Django login form using Okta validation (preferably OIDC).

I checked many articles and modules but I am not able to get it done because of the lack of examples available for the modules especially for beginners. Below are some modules which I tried to use but either it is a lot complicated or it needs a different login page than the Django default login page.

[django-oidc-provider](https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider)

[django-admin-sso](https://github.com/matthiask/django-admin-sso)

[pyoidc](https://github.com/OpenIDC/pyoidc)

[mozila-django-oidc](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc)

[drf-oidc-auth](https://github.com/ByteInternet/drf-oidc-auth)

Either these plugins do not support Django login form as an input form or I am not using the right plugin. Any help is appreciated.